# Javascript фрэймворк..

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, javascript

Добрый день.

Есть необходимость сделать сайт, работающий без единой перезагрузки браузера..

Это реализованно, например в gmail.

Понятное дело, что это все можно сделать ajax запросами, и программированием логики..

Вопрос в том, а есть ли уже что-то подобное ? Что-то типо JQuery Mobile(именно так он и работает.. подгружает ответ сервера, в не делает перезагрузку) но для WEB ?

Comment: всем кто ответил - по еденичке ) Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не требуется что-то экстраординарное, можно использовать связку jQuery + [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) (для улов через hash)

Если требуется навороченный интерфейс (типа gmail) стоит посмотреть в сторону [backbone.js](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/127049/)

Answer (score 4):

А просто jQuery чем не устраивает? Сам использовал, сайт состоит из одной страницы, работает без единой перезагрузки и никаких проблем.

Comment: jquery хорош.. но вот изобретать велосипед не хочется..

Comment: Ай, отказался я от jQuery.... ибо быдло-фрэймворк уже он... устарел :)

Comment: и что тогда сейчас в теме ? )

Comment: Это мы уже начинаем рассуждать о вкусах. Но на мой личный взгляд - любым фреймворком можно пользоваться, главное, чтоб руки из правильного места росли. Всё зависит от посталенных задач и инструмент подбирать надо тот, который для этих задач подходит, но главно это умение этим инструментом пользоваться.
Не соглашусь со Станиславом. Так как нет ничего идеального, то можно говорить о "быдло-кодере", но не о "быдло-фреймворке"

Comment: @Draev, а в чём заключается изобретение велосипеда?

Comment: в том, что хочется тратить время на реализацию непосредственно поставленной задачи, а не на написания фрэймворка на Jquery

Comment: @Deonis, соглашусь.. Вот и пытаюсь найти подходящий фрэймворк..
Естественно, если ничего подходящего не найду, буду пилить ручками.. и именно на JQuery.

Comment: @Draev, я вас не понимаю. Вы не хотите писать свой фреймворк, а хотите готовый. Так в чём же будет изобретение велосипеда, если вы возьмёте jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поискать на [microjs](http://microjs.com/) нужные вам библиотеки и склеить в одном фреймворке. В итоге, фреймворк будет делать ровно то, что вам надо.
Хотя, это будет тот же [mootools](http://mootools.net/core/)...

Answer (score 1):

Пользуй QOOXDOO. Фрэймворк классный, прооопешеный. Есть свои контролы. Очень удобен в использовании.

http://qooxdoo.org

Comment: А без питона на нем никак нельзя ?

Answer (score 1):

А это смотря для чего вам сайт нужен. В любом случае, чтобы не перезагружать страницу - это только через `AJAX`. Если вам нужен сайт красивый, для широкого круга пользователей, то `jQuery` - лучший (из-за высокой популярности и легкой расширяемости). Если вам надо создать какую-то систему управления контентом, сайтом или чем-то там еще, т.е. для администраторов, контент-менеджеров и всякого такого рабочего контингента, то на сегодня лучшее - это ExtJS.

И вы как-то интересно написали

```
Что-то типо JQuery Mobile (...) но для WEB.
```

`JQuery Mobile` - это и есть фреймворк для WEB.

Comment: это фрэймворк оптимизированный под мобильные системы..
У него есть поддкржка специфических ивентов, изменение стилей кнопочек, линков (под айфон..). этого всего мне просто не нужно..

Comment: А. Так даже там все запросы на сервер руками писать надо. Единственное, так там все открытия/закрытия окон вынесены в интерфейсы.  
Но на ExtJS 4 можно менять родительский дизайн. И, получается, получится очень похожая в использовании система на этот мобильный фреймворк. Но вот разбираться надо много времени.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile не советую, много проблем с элементами, которых не существует на момент загрузки страницы. Например, добавление/изменение стилизованных элементов форм. Делаю с ориентацией на планшет Galaxy Tab, а там тормозит ужасно, больше под iOS рассчитан.

Лучше всего на обычном jQuery.